# SqlCommand Parameters not working

Tags: c#

Task:

Replace certain variables within an sql statement with the requisite data.

Issue:

The variables are not being replaced

C# code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
     select 
                 1 [GL], 
                 (
                     select 
                             isnull(COUNT(*), 0)
                         from 
                             @DataDB..APSetup
                 ) [AP],
                 (
                     select 
                             isnull(COUNT(*), 0)
                         from
                             @DataDB..ARSetup
                 ) [AR],
                 (
                     select 
                             isnull(COUNT(*), 0)
                         from 
                             @DataDB..CASetup
                 ) [CA],
                 case 
                     when (
                          select 
                                  isnull(COUNT(*), 0) 
                              from
                                  @DataDB..SalesTax
                          ) > 0 
                         then 1 else 0
                 end [TX], 
                 (
                     select 
                             isnull(COUNT(*), 0)
                         from
                             @DataDB..INSetup
                 ) [IN], 
                 (
                     select
                             isnull(COUNT(*), 0)
                         from 
                             @DataDB..POSetup
                 ) [PO],
                 (
                     select
                             isnull(COUNT(*), 0)
                         from 
                             @DataDB..SOSetup
                 ) [SO], 
                 (
                     select 
                             isnull(COUNT(*), 0)
                         from
                             @DataDB..RQSetup
                 ) [RQ],
                 (
                    select 
                             COUNT(*)
                        from 
                             @DataDB..pcsetup 
                        Where 
                             Setupid = 'PC' AND PERNBR <> ''
                 ) [PJ] 
    from 
          @DataDB..glsetup");

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataDB", CurrentBranch.AppDB);
    AppConnection.InitialCatalog = CurrentBranch.AppDB;
    Modules.AddRange(SqlQueries.DataQuery2(cmd, AppConnection.ConnectionString));
```

Sql Query:

```
select 1 [GL], (select isnull(COUNT(*),0) from @DataDB..APSetup) [AP], (select isnull(COUNT(*),0) from @DataDB..ARSetup) [AR], (select isnull(COUNT(*),0) from @DataDB..CASetup) [CA], case when (select isnull(COUNT(*),0) from @DataDB..SalesTax) > 0 then 1 else 0 end [TX], (select isnull(COUNT(*),0) from @DataDB..INSetup) [IN], (select isnull(COUNT(*),0) from @DataDB..POSetup) [PO], (select isnull(COUNT(*),0) from @DataDB..SOSetup) [SO], (select isnull(COUNT(*),0) from @DataDB..RQSetup) [RQ],  (select COUNT(*) from @DataDB..pcsetup Where Setupid = 'PC' AND PERNBR <> '') [PJ] from @DataDB..glsetup
```

Question:

Why does the variable replacement not work?

Additional Information:

The issue is not the query, when I manually replace the @DataDB with its intended value it works fine.

The issue is the C# SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue();

Comment: Reading your sql query is killing my eyes by the way..

Comment: try cleaning up your SQL Command please this is not very readable.. thanks

Comment: Why is that? and also I didn't write the sql query, we have a guy for that

Comment: Also the issue is not the query, the issue is that the scalar variables are not being replaced

Comment: then show the full query.. what the heck is `...` in that query ..? come on now

Comment: before finding the needle, sort the haystack.

Comment: you should learn how to write a correct / readable Parameterized query.. this is hard to make heads or tails out of what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: As stated, I am trying to replace the variables withing the Query, with there values

Comment: What is `CurrentBranch.AppDB`?

Comment: Jodrell Thank you for your thoughtful suggestions so far, @DJ KRAZE I would suggest you learn how to give constructive criticism in the future as your comments unfortunately do not help anyone, with anything and would dissuade individuals from coming to there peers for help.

Comment: @Jodrell, or just get a big magnet.

Comment: @Jodrell did you just reference yourself in a comment by yourself to yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is because you can't parameterize what database/table you are trying to select from. You can't do: `select * from @SomeTable` You already are doing this in C#, just do this:

(snipped for clarity sake):

```
string sql = string.Format("select isnull(COUNT(*),0) from {0}..APSetup)...", CurrentBranch.AppDB);
```

Comment: finally someone who read the question!

Comment: @jvanh1 expidite answers by making the question more readable.

Comment: @jvanh1 since all the tables are in the same database, why not just set the database on your connection (which is probably already the case) and omit all the database name prefixing? It would make your job simpler, and the query shorter and more readable, more maintainable etc....

Comment: Because we loop through a dynamic series of databases that change from one run to the next, the connection is also changed dynamically, and as I have stated before I have no control over how the sql commands are written

Comment: @jvanh1, in fact you explicity set the database `AppConnection.InitialCatalog = CurrentBranch.AppDB;` you don't need to specify in the statement.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with @Jodrell, you set the InitialCatalog, so I'm not sure why you have to then specify it in your query string as well. The reason why databases allow you to set the database (like you're doing) is precisely so you DON'T need to do things like this.

Comment: When we did not at times it would attempt to run the query in the wrong context, this was the solution developed for that

Comment: @jvanh1 but, the database doesen't change mid statement. If you can't change the SQL how will the erroneous parameter usage be removed?

Comment: That seems like a bandaid though. Maybe you weren't closing the original connection? What is IntialCatalog? That's not part of SqlConnection. Is that a wrapper you wrote around SqlConnection? When you call it, does it turn around and call `SqlConnection.ChangeDatabase`?

Comment: No, as far as I can tell the original connection is closed, believe me there is more than one bandaid in this program...unfortunately I am not in charge of it.

Comment: the initialCatalog is part of SQLConnectionStringBuilder